# windowClosing() method is not getting called

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, awt, windowlistener

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test  {

    Test() {
        JFrame f=new JFrame("CloseIt");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(400,200);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void WindowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.out.print("In Windowclosing opr");
                f.dispose();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Test t=new Test();
    }
}
```

I actually wanted to ask the user whether he wants to save the file before closing it.
But whenever I close the frame (cross button), nothing happens.
`windowClosing()` is not even getting called.

Answer (score 2):

You named your method `WindowClosing()`.

The method that get's called is however `windowClosing()`.

The best recommendation is to annotate your methods with `@Override` so that the compiler knows that you want to override a method and can produce an error message if your method doesn't override a superclass method:

```
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
        {
            ...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `WindowClosing()` method as `windowClosing()`

how about my solution yours one is right too.

```
  addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                int confirmedPane = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                        "Are you sure you want to exit the program?",
                        "Exit Program Message Box",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                if (confirmedPane == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    System.out.println("Yes is the option");
                } else {
                    dispose();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: (1-) no need to clutter the forum with a duplicate answer. The problem about fixing the typo was given two hours earlier.